# Not able to execute the java class files in ubuntu

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, java

I am new to java. I started installing oracle java in ubuntu 64 bit machine and I set the CLASS_PATH

`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_40
  set PATH="$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin"`

If I put following command `java -version` in terminal it was saying **1.8 oracle java** and `javac -version` **javac 1.8.0_40**

Then I created a java file and I was able to compile and execute the file. Now I installed tomcat7. now if I put `java -version` it is displaying

```
java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.13.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

and for **javac -version**

```
javac 1.8.0_40
```

But now I am able to compile the same java file which I compiled and run before but not I am not able to execute the file.  it is saying following error ..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 791289926 in class file TestBean
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

From this I can understand the javac is 1.8(oracle) and java is 1.7(openjdk). Now I need to configure to java 1.8(oracle). How will I do that? Also If I give the oracle jre full path **(/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_40/jre/bin/java)** when executing java class file it is executing. If anyone know solutions please give me......

Comment: try to set `JRE_HOME`

Comment: This is more about configuration of your Ubuntu; in that sense your question is better suited on askubuntu.com or maybe superuser.com. One way is to simply force a JAVA/JRE home in .profile, or .bashrc, ... but there are more sophisticated methods; for example using galternatives ..

Comment: You're compiling with 1.8 and executing with 1.7

Comment: @m0skit0 ya you are correct.. but I don't wish to have openjdk.. this is creating problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you really set the CLASS_PATH variable? Unless you had a very specific reason you should unset that, it'll cause problems if you don't know what you are doing.

In order to configure which JDK is used on Ubuntu you should use:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

As documented in the Ubuntu help page for Java - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java

Comment: Hi, Chase, I got the solution now.. with the above command. Thanks for your help. Good day.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Java_Home again like following:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java
```

Comment: what does this give you?

JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/java java -version

Comment: 'java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.13.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)'

Answer (score 1):

You need to compile the .class file and run it with the same java version. So in your case, compile the .class file again and try to run it, that should work.

That's why when you compile the file with the full javac path it works. Mixing JDK and JRE versions it's not a good idea.

Comment: First of all thank you for giving me suggestion, but I want to get rid out of this confusion. I am not mixing  them, you can understand my prob if you read my question. They are automatically mixing. I don't want open JDK..

Answer (score 1):

Set your class path in /etc/profile 
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_40
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin